Failed to update the model when i tried to send raw json data in Yii (PHP)
I was trying to send a request using Postman to update a field in my database. However, I kept encountering the following error:

{ "status": "error", "message": "Invalid request method or invalid
data submission." }.

Firstly, I checked my Postman settings to ensure the Content-Type header was set to application/json. I also checked that my request type is Post and I that I was sending RAW JSON data.
Secondly, I changed my function  to read raw JSON data using the following code:
$data = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams();

But it didn't work and I continued to have the same mistake. I've tried DEBUGGING by adding code like
\Yii::debug($model->getDirtyAttributes(), 'dirtyAttributes');
\Yii::debug($model->attributes, 'attributesAfterLoad');

This didn't help either, as sending raw JSON data leaves the global $_POST array empty. I also received the following message in the terminal:

[Mon Sep 30 12:52:26 2024] [::1]:52291 Closed without sending a
request;It was probably just an unused speculative preconnection.

Here is my method:
public function actionUpdate($id)
{

$model = $this->findModel($id);

if (\Yii::$app->request->isPut) {
    $data = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams();
    
    if ($model->load($data, '') && $model->save()) {
        return [
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'Model updated successfully.',
            'data' => $model,
        ];
    } else {
        return [
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Failed to update the model.',
            'errors' => $model->errors,
        ];
    }
}

return [
    'status' => 'error',
    'message' => 'Invalid request method or invalid data submission.',
];

}

Are you sure the problem is directly related to any database? If your application can't even read the JSON data properly, I would assume the database isn't even part of your problem

Invalid request method or invalid data submission - the code you've shared does not contain any such error message. Did you check where in your application this message is generated? Then set a breakpoint exactly there, and re-run the request

The answer is I had to add to my config/web.php these lines:
 'components' => [

        'request' => [

            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]

        ],

U also can check official documentation about this Class yii\web\JsonParser
